# Android barcode (Crash when back button is pressed)

Tags: java, android

Whenever I press the scan button for scanning the barcode, when I press the back button, it crashed . I want to make it when the back button is pressed, it will resume back the main activity. Can anyone know what's the problem for my code ?

```
HomeActivity.java

public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public String codeFormat,codeContent;
public TextView formatTxt, contentTxt, price, productName, productDate;
public String name,date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_price);
    productName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_name);
    productDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_date);

}// end HomeActivity class

public void scanNow(View view){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a Bar Code");
    integrator.setResultDisplayDuration(0);
    integrator.setWide();  // Wide scanning rectangle, may work better for 1D barcodes
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.initiateScan();
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        price(codeContent);
        codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        codeFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

        // display it on screen
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + codeFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + codeContent);
        price.setText("PRICE: " + "RM" + price(codeContent) );
        productName.setText("ITEM: " + name);
        productDate.setText("EXPIRY DATE: " + date);

        Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inventory_add);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("");
                builder.setMessage("Add this product to inventory? ");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {


                    }

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No",null);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        });

    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }

}

public double price( String codeContent )

{
    final String array[] = {"9789834508654","9556404116409"};
    final String productName[] = {"MATHEMATICS for MATRICULATION SEMESTER 1 . THIRD EDITION",};
    final String productDate[] = {"", "13/1/2018"};
    final double price1[] = {50.00,1.60};
    double price = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++ )
    {
        if(codeContent.equals(array[x]))
        {
            price = price1[x];
            name = productName[x];
            date = productDate[x];
            break;
        }
    }

    return price;

}


}




                                                                             --------- beginning of crash
```

04-21 15:02:20.190 9700-9700/in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner, PID: 9700
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=0, data=null} to activity {in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner/in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner.HomeActivity.price(HomeActivity.java:113)
                                                                                     at in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner.HomeActivity.onActivityResult(HomeActivity.java:57)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: We can know a lot more easily if you post the stacktrace from the crash

Comment: done , i have added the error code below my source code.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using `codeContent` before assigning a value to it:

```
//we have a relult
price(codeContent);
codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
```

You could flip those lines:

```
//we have a relult
codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
price(codeContent);
```

Actually the exception stacktrace is telling you exactly that:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at in.aurora.android_barcode_scanner.HomeActivity.price(HomeActivity.java:112)
```

That means `price()` tried to check for string equality but it threw an exception because the reference is null

Comment: tried to flip those line that you have mentioned ... but no luck :( issit possible for u to help me to fix that error and paste the fixed source code in here ? please and thank you very much !

Comment: Actually no. But me and the whole SO community would love to guide you to find a solution by yourself. What's the new error? Is it still null? You can edit and update your question to keep us up to date on your progress.

Comment: I have tried flip those line that you have mentioned, the error code is still the same . I have updated the error code at the top . The price() method causing my application to crash ....